# c# Interface namespace prefix

Tags: c#, interface, prefix

Let's suppose I have this interface IRepository

```
 public interface IRepository
 {
    #region User
        IUser AddUser(String userName, String password, String email);
        IUser FindUser(String identifier);
    #endregion User

    #region Product
        IProduct AddProduct(...);
        void RemoveProduct(...);
    #endregion Product
}
```

This is very basic until now and I can do things like

```
IRepository MyRepository = new Repository(...);
MyRepository.AddUser(...);
MyRepository.RemoveProduct(...);
```

Ideally, I want something similare to this

```
public interface IRepository
{
    #region User
        IUser User.User(String userName, String password, String email);
        IUser User.Find(String identifier);
    #endregion User

    #region Product
        IProduct Product.Add(...);
        void Product.Remove(...);
    #endregion Product
}
```

Unfortunately, this is not accepted in C#. I cannot add these prefixes.

I want to use this ***kind of namespace*** to write something similar to this

```
IRepository MyRepository = new Repository(...);
MyRepository.User.Add(...);
MyRepository.Product.Remove(...);
```

I don't want to add User and Product objects to my Interface as all I need is a way to improve the reading by this kind of prefixes.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: -1 for breaking SRP (Single Responsibility Principle)

Comment: I do agree that the example may lead to this.
Suppose now it is not a repository but a blind service talking to my datastore. I has one responsibility : Talking to my backstore

Answer (score 3):

Split it into two separate interfaces.

```
public interface IRepositoryUser
{
    IUser Add(String userName, String password, String email);
    IUser Find(String identifier);
}

public interface IRepositoryProduct
{
    IProduct Add(...);
    void Remove(...);
}

public interface IRepository
{
    IRepositoryUser User { get; }
    IRepositoryProduct Product { get; }
}
```

Comment: -1: And what will he do, when he wants to add a `Remove` method for users?

Comment: Fixed that already - I was copying and pasting, but used the wrong code snippet to start with. Noticed that just after posting.

Comment: ok. And what is the difference to his first approach now in a class that implements IRepository?

Comment: @Daniel, good point. See my most recent edit, which implements pretty much what the OP is asking (as I read the original question). Either way, you have a logical separation between the `Product` and `User` entities. AFAIR, `.` is not legal in any identifier name in C#, so this is about the closest one can get.

Comment: ok. But he doesn't want to do that, see his last sentence. Sorry for being such a pain in the ass ;-)

Comment: Well, we can always petition Microsoft to make `.` a legal character in identifier names. There's opening a can of worms if I ever saw it... :) (I can hear the echo of "closed as WONTFIX" already)

Comment: Removed my downvote, because now you are saying the same as most of the others: Split it.

Comment: I think the root of the problem is that he wants to use a character inside identifier names that is not valid as a part of an identifier name. I stand by my suggestion to split the responsibilities, but I suppose one *possible* way around this would be to use a character that is valid inside identifier names, such as `_`.

Comment: @Michael, you're right. It is all about this very small character in identifer names. I may solve my problem and all I need is to use another legal one like "_"

Answer (score 1):

What you want, is not legal in the C# syntax as you already realized.
I suggest you stick with your first version. It is clear, readable and conforms to the default naming conventions.

Comment: There are so many things that are not legal and people found way to go around. That's what I want

Answer (score 1):

**Answer if you're talking about repository pattern:**

In my humild opinion, and based on my experience, why are you mixing products and users?

Why you want to prefix repository methods?

Just create a repository for any domain object type "IUserRepository" and "IProductRepository" and you won't have such strange requirement.

I don't know if you have this feature in another programming language, but, even if you've it or not, I find a bad design making a repository reponsible of more than a domain object type.

---

**Answer if you're talking about anything else**

You would need to separate concerns too.

For example, you would have a data service and you want to manage users and products. I'd suggest you create two managers: UsersManager and ProductsManager.

Both would be associated to a DataServiceManager so you can have something like this:

```
DataServiceManager dataServiceMan = new DataServiceManager();
dataServiceMan.Users.RegisterUser(...);
dataServiceMan.Products.CreateProduct(...);
```

Comment: I agree. pierreBise wouldnt have this kind of problem if he carefuly separated both parts.

Comment: OK, I would have called it DataService instead of Repository. I have one DataService taking responsibily for talking to my background store. I don't care how many entities are there.

Comment: Well, since programming or computing is a science you should care about calling things with the right name, because it's not the same a "repository" than anything else. You've to be more specific. I'm going to update the answer, but be more accurate next time. Thanks.

Comment: @Matias, totally agree about the naming in computing and programming.
Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: @Matias, As I said in the original post, I don't want to add objects because I don't know them. I have one service giving orders to the background. It is all about writing clarification in the code.

Comment: But I believe you want a language feature missing in C#. You need to accept this fact, and, anyway, since you don't want to use composition, you've no way to have nothing similar to your expectations. You should autoanswer your question as you don't get any right answer for that (you want "namespaces" for class members... impossible!! haha).

Answer (score 1):

What about defining the `Add` method in `IUser` and the `Remove` method in `IProduct` and then in your `IRepository` just define `IUser User {get; set;}` and `IProduct Product {get; set;}`.

I believe then your syntax `MyRepository.User.Add(...);` and 
`MyRepository.Product.Remove(...);` will be fine.

Comment: As I already mentioned, I do not want to add objects to my Interface.

Comment: Agree that is what you said. But, so you don't want force the implementer of the `IRepository` interface to implement the 2 objects, YET you want to force it to have 2 methods that work on those objects? What does the implemented method `RemoveProduct` do when the `Product` object is not implemented?

Answer (score 0):

I think is better separate logic for performing different Entities in different Repositories classes
and in base IRepository keep only common methods like Add Remove Save Update etc.
for example

```
interface IRepository
{
   void Save();
   //other common methods
}
interface IProductRepository:IRepository
 {
   //Methods specified for products
 }
```

Comment: I do agree that the name is misleading.
Suppose it is a service and not a repository
I want to have one service talking blindly to my datastore. It does not have any knowledge about entities.

Answer (score 0):

The is generally solved using generics so you would have

```
  interface IRepository<T>

{
   T FindAll()
   T FindSingle(string id)

}
```

then implement derived classes based on the interface, almost always bloating your interfaces isnt the way to go and breaks [ISP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you are need explicit interface implementation, like sample below:

```
    ....................
    interface IOne
    {
       void MethodOne();
    }

    interface ITwo
    {
        void MethodTwo();
    }

    interface IThree
    {
        void MethodThree();
    }

    class TestIf : IOne, ITwo, IThree
    {
        void IThree.MethodThree()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Method three");                
        }

        void IOne.MethodOne()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Method one");
        }

        void ITwo.MethodTwo()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Method two");
        }
    }
    ...................
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TestIf t = new TestIf();

        IOne one = t as IOne;
        ITwo two = t as ITwo;
        IThree three = t as IThree;

        one.MethodOne();
        two.MethodTwo();
        three.MethodThree();

    }
```

Pay attention, in such approach you can call interface methods only by explicitly convert object to specified interface

Comment: I investigated this option of explicit Interfaces and I would have nearly there if I could be able to write **t.one.MethodOne**

Comment: Now, I have understand your iam, unfortunately, I think you have no way except of creation User and Product objects in your Interface

Comment: One suggestion more,but this is workaround. You can use interfaces this way `(t as IOne).MethodOne();`